# Is it possible to use HttpBrowserCapabilities from a c# console application?

Tags: c#, http, parsing, browser, user-agent

I need to parse UserAgent strings from a console app and this seems like a simple way to do it, but I obviously don't have an HttpRequest object and can't seem to make a fake one with a User-Agent header (I get platform not supported exception). Is there any way to do this, or should I start exploring other alternatives to user agent parsing?

Comment: what kind of page request you want to capture???? specially from console app?

Comment: No page request. I have a list of user agents in a text file and I want to parse out Browser, Version, OS and a couple other things - all of which would have been available through Request.Browser, but now I'm trying to get them from a console app and list of UserAgent strings.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The `User-Agent` header can be parsed by the `HttpBrowserCapabilities` class with the help of a [BrowserCapabilitiesFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.browsercapabilitiesfactory.aspx), as follows:

```
var userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.2.10) " +
                "Gecko/20100914 Firefox/3.6.10";
var browser = new HttpBrowserCapabilities {
    Capabilities = new Hashtable {{string.Empty, userAgent}}
};
var factory = new BrowserCapabilitiesFactory();
factory.ConfigureBrowserCapabilities(new NameValueCollection(), browser);
```

Comment: I want to run this outside of an asp.net environment (analyzing log files).  It doesn't seem to be determining the agent type and version very well.  "Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/37.0.2062.120+Safari/537.36" = Chrome 37, but "Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/4.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+.NET4.0E;+InfoPath.3;+SynapseWorkstation.3.2.1;+MS-RTC+LM+8;+Tablet+PC+2.0)" = Mozilla.