# Passing language preference to HtmlAgilityPack when retrieving web pages

Tags: c#, http-headers, console-application, html-agility-pack, fizzler

my aim is to read out specific container/tags/attributes from a web site(for my hobby), everything works except getting the german translation for my value (which I usually get when manually open the site in my browser(may be the web site gets the specific information from the user agent), but if I use my program it will only give me the english value)

The working c# console code:

```
   List<string> href = new List<string>();
    List<string> titles = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        var webOverview = new HtmlWeb();
        var documentOverview = webOverview.Load("http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?page=0&format=[%22Commander%22]");
            webOverview.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:32.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0";//updated
            webOverview.AutoDetectEncoding = true;//updated
        var pageOverview = documentOverview.DocumentNode;

        HtmlNode[] hrefList = pageOverview.QuerySelectorAll("td.leftCol").ToArray();
        HtmlNode[] titleList = pageOverview.QuerySelectorAll("div.cardInfo").ToArray();

        for (int rowcounter = 0; rowcounter < hrefList.Count(); rowcounter++)
        {
            var hrefValue = hrefList[rowcounter].QuerySelector("a").Attributes["href"].Value;
            var titleValue = titleList[rowcounter].QuerySelector("span.cardTitle").InnerText;

            href.Add(hrefValue);
            titles.Add(titleValue);
            Console.WriteLine(rowcounter.ToString() + ". " + hrefValue + ": " + titleValue + "\n\n");
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine("Links: " + href.Count + " Titles: " + titles.Count + "\n");
```

In my browser I see something like this "Schlachthaus-Ghul (Abattoir Ghoul)"(without setting language properties), but if I excecute my program I get "Abattoir Ghoul", which has been produced by the statement

```
HtmlNode[] titleList = pageOverview.QuerySelectorAll("div.cardInfo").ToArray();
```

but I need this " "Schlachthaus-Ghul (Abattoir Ghoul)", instead of just the english text

May be I need something like this  [user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891640/is-it-possible-to-use-httpbrowsercapabilities-from-a-c-sharp-console-application)  and I could not find a pramameter in the URL,which tells the server I want also german in the title information?

*I updated two lines(commentary) and it does/did not change anything.(user agent from http://www.whatsmyuseragent.com*

Comment: Have you tried to set `webOverview.UserAgent` ?

Comment: Are you able to detect encoding? you can set by webOverview.AutoDetectEncoding = true;

Comment: thanks, for helping. I updated it, but the result is the same as before.

Comment: There is a lot of javascript, it is perhaps modified (translated) by this javascript. When I browse to that page I do not see the german translation.

Comment: See this link, perhaps it would be a way to go. http://stackoverflow.com/a/25854559/2224701

Comment: The language comes from Accept-Language not User-Agent

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll need to tell the server that you expect a German page by sending it the "Accept-Language" header:

```
var webOverview = new HtmlWeb();
webOverview.PreRequest += (request) =>
{
    request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "de-DE");
    return true;
};
var documentOverview = webOverview.Load("http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?page=0&format=[%22Commander%22]");
```

Which is basically a short for:

```
public void Yourmethod()
{
   var webOverview = new HtmlWeb();
   webOverview.PreRequest += SendGermanLanguageHeaders;

   var documentOverview = webOverview.Load("http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?page=0&format=[%22Commander%22]");
}

private bool SendGermanLanguageHeaders(HttpWebRequest request)
{
   request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "de-DE");
   return true;
}
```

The lambda construct defines an anonymous method, short, inline and in context. That method is then added to the `PreRequest` event handler list using the `+=` construct you're probably familiar with. [More about this construct can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx).

Comment: what kind of structure is this ? " webOverview.PreRequest += (request) =>
 {
     request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "de-DE");
     return true;
 };" registering an event + lambda expression... never saw this ... can you explain this -please?